# kermit - how to redirect output into a file

Tags: linux, kermit

i'm using kerimt to print the data coming from /dev/ttyS1.
i'm running kermit as root user( sudo ) because setting the stream source command:

> set line /dev/ttyS1

doesn't work otherwise.
i'm trying to redirect the output using this command:

> set session ./out.log

but i get this error:

> ?Write permission denied - ./out.log

if i run kermit with my regular user( without sudo ), i'm able to set the log file but i can't set the stream source ( the set line command ), i'm getting this error:

> /var/lock: Permission denied
>   Sorry, write access to UUCP lockfile directory denied.

how can i solve these permission issues?
is there a better way to redirect the output into a file?

Answer (score 2):

If you want all your session to be logged (including carriage-return and line-feed characters) try:

```
set session-log binary
log session <filename>
```

if you are still having problems with the permission try to change the ownership of your output file with:

```
sudo chown <username>:<username> out.log
```

For further information on log-session types with Kermit see this page: http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/logserial.html

Comment: Thanks, i ended up not using Kermit but screen instead, it was simpler.